# Transforming each item in an array into an object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm wondering how I can transform an each item in an array into a specified object. You can see the code below for the array I start out with and the result I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to use the `map` function to no avail, and not sure if the `array.map()` function is the right function to use, or if maybe there is something in lodash that I could use. Thanks!

```
const x = ["a", "b", "c"];

// expected result
{
  "a": {"foo": "bar"},
  "b": {"foo": "bar"},
  "c": {"foo": "bar"},
}
```

Comment: What is `{ foo: 'bar' }`? Where does it come from?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `forEach`: `let res = {}; x.forEach(e => res[e] = {'foo': 'bar'});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the new objects with the wanted key and assign to a single object.

```js
const
    x = ["a", "b", "c"],
    object = Object.assign(...x.map(k => ({ [k]: { foo: "bar" } })));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array#reduce()`

```js
const x = ["a", "b", "c"];

const res = x.reduce((a,c)=> (a[c] = {foo:'bar'},a) , {})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    const x = ["a", "b", "c"];    
    const transformedObject = x.reduce((acc, el) => {acc[el] = {"foo": "bar"}; return acc}, {})

    console.log(transformedObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

**lodash 1:**

you can use [`_.zipObject()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#zipObject) with `Array.map()`:

```js
const data = ["a", "b", "c"];

const result = _.zipObject(data, data.map(() => ({ for: 'bar' })));
 
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Lodash 2:**

You can use `Array.reduce()` with [`_.set()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#set):

```js
const data = ["a", "b", "c"];

const result = data.reduce((r, c) => _.set(r, `${c}.foo`, 'bar'), {});
 
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```